# How to install UC berkeley's OCTTOOLS

Tags: linux

I need someone to help me and teach me step by step how to install OCTTOOLS on Linux, and make it possible for me to run the MisII program smoothly inside. I have been trying for a long time but I cannot find the correct method, and I cannot find any information on the internet.

I have downloaded octtools-5.1.tar.gz from UC Berkeley, extracted it, and inside the folder there is an OCT5.1.base.tar.Z which I also extracted. Then I tried to run PREINSTALL and INSTALL, but I did not get the result I wanted. I hope to be able to use it smoothly, like in this picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bL7w0.jpg)

Comment: `did not get the result I wanted`, what results did you get?

Answer (score 1):

Extract the folder to let's say /opt directory:

```
tar xvf octools-5.1.tar.gz -C /opt
```

Set the path variables:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/octools/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/octools/lib
```

Then run the octools:

```
octools
```

After that, you can run MisII program in another terminal:

```
MisII input_file output_file
```